# Can Meliodas be permanently killed?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

So, if I understand correctly, for a curse he has on him Meliodas resurrected. Does this mean there isnt a way to permanently kill him? Is there something that can be done to permanently kill him?

Comment: Lift the curse?

Comment: lol who cursed him, and can it be lifted? @JoeW

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin More is revealed as the story progresses.